# Creepage on SMT DIP package with an NC pin

Tags: high-voltage, solid-state-relay, creepage

I'm having trouble understanding how the CPC1972GSTR can have the specs it does.

Here's the [datasheet](http://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/0/E16FD7FE1462A2DD852570F800586DFD/$file/CPC1972.pdf).

In particular, it has a blocking voltage spec of 800V, but if you look at the recommended footprint, there's the NC pin between the two switch pins.

Doesn't the presence of that pin reduce the creepage distance between the two switch pins? Even if it's NC, it's still *conductive*, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some additional background  **[from CAN/CSA-C22.2 NO. 60950-1-07 ♦ UL 60950-1](https://composter.com.ua/documents/IEC60950-1.pdf)**

> (snip) CREEPAGE DISTANCES shall be so dimensioned that, for a given RMS WORKING VOLTAGE and pollution degree, no flashover or breakdown of insulation (for example, due to tracking) will occur.

Depending on the degree of dust and humidity there exists a Pollution Level (PL) defined in the spec as Level 1,2 where PCB creepage is defined for ever range of Vac rms levels but for  600Vac they have a creepage ratio  of 350Vrms/mm for PL1 and 200Vrms/mm for PL2.

This PCB pad geometry is **2.54mm pitch** with **0.65mm pad width** which for 2 pitches provides (2.54-0.65)*2 = **3.78mm** which at PL2 gives a 756V result  **so a 600V creepage rating seems valid.**

- Note these breakdown levels are also air pressure sensitive and high altitudes above 2km require 50% higher creepage gaps.  [( FWIW on arc thesis)](http://lib.tkk.fi/Dipl/2012/urn100737.pdf)

Comment: The breakdown voltage is 800V, though. It’s purely an academic question at that level though. As long as PL 2 (which seems appropriate for the inside of a IP67 chassis) supports 240 VAC my immediate concerns are addressed.

Answer (score 2):

It does, but only by the width of the pin. While the pin is conductive, it is not shorted to either active pin.

Even if it were, you need to specify the standard you're applying. For instance, using the calculator at [this site](https://www.smps.us/pcbtracespacing.html) establishes that for IPC2221B, 800 volts requires a coated spacing of 67.7 mils, and the recommended footprint for the part establishes a 75 mil spacing.

Accepting that the floating pin simply reduces the total spacing, the footprint provides a 150 mil clearance, and IPC2221B requires 157.7 mils, which is very close.